# Using the value _T("") and CString variables

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, c-strings

This might sounds simple but I want to know if one way is actually more efficient.

Example one:

- `CString strName = _T("");`
- `CString strName = CString();`

Example two:

- `if (strFilterText == _T(""))`
- `if (strFilterText.IsEmpty())`

Is there any negative impact is using `_T("")` in this way? And if so, why?

Comment: Just plan `CString strName;` to declare an empty string. `IsEmpty()` should in principle be fastest for checking empty string (since it's dedicated to the task, it can use whatever technique is most efficient), though I suspect the difference is immeasurably small.

Comment: At this point in time you should not be using `_T("")` anymore; but `L""` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CString` has different constructors and [operator overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), it is prepared for different scenarios. It's a complicated class but in general, such classes work like this:

Use default constructor `CString()` (initializes for `_T("")`):

```
CString s1 = CString();     
CString s2;                 //same as above, shortcut
CString s3{};               //same as above
CString s4 = {};            //same as above
```

Use copy constructor `CString(const CString& src)`:

```
const CString src = _T("");

CString s1 = CString(src);  
CString s2 = src;           //same as above
CString s3 = { src};        //same as above
CString s4(src);            //same as above
```

Use different constructor `CString(const TCHAR* src)`:

```
const TCHAR* src = _T("");

CString s1 = CString(src);  
CString s2 = src;           //same as above
CString s3 = { src };       //same as above
CString s4(src);            //same as above
```

`CString` also supports `=` assignment operator:

```
CString s;
s = _T("");                 //uses `=` assignment operator

s = CString();              //uses default constructor for right side, 
                            //calls `=` assignment operator for left side.
```

---

`==` operator overload may use `CString::Compare` to compare the two sides. So

`if (s == _T(""))` is same as `if (s.Compare(_T("")) == 0)`, it might be 1 nanosecond slower than `s.IsEmpty()`, otherwise is valid.

Comment: For complementness, I missing here CString s1(src).  I think it's could be faster than CString s1 = src.

Comment: @tom `CString s1(src)` and `CString s1 = src` are **exactly** identical.

Comment: @tom Note that the assignment operator is not called in `CString s1 = src;` The compiler uses the matching constructor (updated answer)